# What is volume of sound?

Tags: waves, acoustics

Is there another term for (volume of sound)?
What is the relation between intensity and sound volume?

Comment: If there is an answer that satisfies your question could you please go ahead and mark it as "the answer" so that people who search for something similar (or have the exact same question) can find the answer easily?

Comment: Of course I am new here so I didn’t know about it, thank you for telling me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Volume" seems to be something of an imprecise term that can be used to mean different things, though it is usually considered to be the same or nearly the same thing as "loudness", the subjective measurement of how loud a sound seems to the human ear.

Loudness does correlate with intensity, but frequency is also a factor, since our ears have different levels of sensitivity to different frequencies.

Comment: Thank you, I believed that it was  the same as loudness but i wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean loudness if you talk of volume of sound.
The intensity of a sound is the power of the sound in Watts divided by the area the sound covers in square meters. The loudness of a sound relates the intensity of any given sound to the intensity at the threshold of hearing. It is measured in decibels (dB).
the definition of dB you can look up for example in wikipedia

Comment: Thank you, I believed that it was  the same as loudness but i wanted to confirm it